# How do I communicate with remote servers from an iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to create an application which can communicate with my central server database.

Example: One time registration for every user and I want to store registration data to my server database and show all users to show the list of all registered users.

What I have to do to implement this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `NSURLConnection` class to get this done. Alternatively, you can use `ASIHTTPRequest`, which, IMO, is much easier and user friendly. You can find `ASIHTTPRequest` here as well as detailed guide on how to set it up and use it: [ASIHHTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Comment: And use it in combination with JSON is the least straining on the device. (small message easy to parse) Parsing can be done with JSON kit which is really fast. https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Answer (score 1):

Despite the advice you will get to use ASIHTTPRequest, or a variety of other frameworks that say they simplify networking, be aware that [ASIHTTPRequest is no longer under active development](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;).

If you are unsure about networking - just use the [NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) path. It really isn't difficult to get up and running with it, and it works asynchronously with about 4 delegate calls. It's fast, built in, well integrated, well documented, and actively developed.

And, if in your application writing career, you think you might want to move on to using any other of these asynchronous networking wrappers, you'll be able to read the code, understand how they each handle different problems in different ways because you've had to face those problems while writing code yourself, and you'll be able to make an **informed** choice about which wrapper to use, rather than just picking one at random.